# Unable to configure picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, dependent-picklist

In case page layout, we have a custom filed (Pick list) that control by service area and in some scenario,

I need to control by another field too (filter it by second field) ,but I could not find any thing .

The issue is how filter the pick list data with 2 field (control by 2 filed)? Please let me know you need more information.

Comment: a dependent picklist can only have one controlling field; workarounds to this involve VF